# Google Tag Manager Twitter Universal Website Tag Event Parameters

Tags: twitter, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to implement Twitter conversion tracking using Google Tag Manager (GTM). In GTM there is a tag type of Twitter Universal Website Tag which has lots of extra purchase related parameters.

- value : transaction price, usually in USD or GBP.
- currency : e.g. `GBP`
- order_id : e.g. `INVOICE-5678`
- num_items : Number of items that were purchased.
- content_ids : comma seperated list of item ids, ie. `['prod_1','prod_2','prod_3']`
- content_category : Category of the page or product

When I use the twitter pixel helper, none of these values is being registered even though they're being passed through from the `dataLayer.`

Does anyone know if Twitter uses these extra parameters when tracking conversions? I cannot see anything about in twitter GTM documentation.

I've been to this page:-

Twitter Help Page

And when it gets to the "For more information about tag events and required parameters, see the Twitter Help Centre".

The standard twitter conversion tracking code only allows for two params to be tracked.

`tw_sale_amount and tw_order_quantity`

Are these really the only parameters it takes?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the GTM Universal Twitter Tag does work, but I had implimented the content_ids incorrectly. NOTE : If content_ids are not working for your twitter tag, it usually means your whole twitter tag is not working.

It needed to be a json_encoded array to work. All working correctly since I made this change. It also fixed my Facebook Tag integration.

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
/* EXAMPLE */


$content_ids = [];

foreach ( $product_items as $product_item_data ) {
    $content_ids[] = $product_item_data['product_item_sku'];
}

$tag_manager_data = array('content_ids'     => json_encode( $content_ids ),
                          'price_data'      => $price_data,
                          'currency'        => $currency,
                          'item_count'      => $item_count );
```

Then in your view / html file you can do the following:-

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
<script>
var tag_manager_data = <?php echo json_encode( $tag_manager_data ); ?>;
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.dataLayer.push({
    'value'             : tag_manager_data.price_data,
    'currency'          : tag_manager_data.currency,
    'content_category'  : 'Checkout',
    'content_ids'       : tag_manager_data.content_ids,
    'event'             : 'InitiateCheckout'
});

</script>
```

Hope this helps someone. The above code is representative only and clearly needs more error checking.